# When users request access to our list and are approved, they are added as a single user instead of added into a group?

Tags: list, permissions, list-view

I have a "Team Visitors" SharePoint permission group which give read and approve access to a list that has a form (Intake Form).

When users request access to this list, and we approve them, they are added as a single user to the permissions tab in the ribbon with "edit" access.

Is there a way to automatically send them into the "Team Visitors" group instead of being an individual entity on the permissions tab?

I do not want new members to join with "edit", I want them to be automatically added into "Team Visitors" which have "read" and "approve" access (in order to create a form and read the listview).

[image]

Edit:

I do not get the choice to select a permission group in the drop down of the approval prompt:

[image]

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same issue and was just about to the raise the question on here. I want to automatically add the requester to a group instead of giving them permission to particular page/document.

Answer (score 6):

On the screen where you approve access, click the ellipsis, and then select the 'Permission' dropdown to grant rights or add them to a group.

[image: Access request]

Comment: Hi James, I tried your suggestion but I do not receive the "select a group or permission level" in the approval prompt. I updated the thread with another screenshot to demonstrate what I have. It is only a drop-down box with rudimentary levels of access, I cannot select my "Team Visitors" permissions group.

Comment: Interesting.  It at least looks like custom permission levels show up as you can see 'Contribute - No Delete' in the list.  Can you add a corresponding Permission Level that matches your requirements for Read and Approve?  I know it isn't as elegant as directly adding to the group but would give you an OOTB method of satisfying the need.  Here is a link with instructions on how to build a custom permission level.  https://billing.plexhosted.com/knowledgebase/278/How-to-create-a-new-SharePoint-2013-permissions-level-.html

Comment: Thank you James, I will definitely take a look at the link you provided. In the meantime, and as a short-term solution, which access setting would be most appropriate for me to set for users that are accessing my list form and I only want them to read it or be able to create a form? Is it Approve? Maybe Contribute?

Comment: I don't think Approve will work for you as it gives many other permissions. 
 It only takes 10 minutes to create a new permission level.  Compare the existing 'Read' and 'Approve' levels.  Start by checking everything that matches 'Read' and then add what you need for 'Approve'.